# Should we tag a DBMS when asking design or normalization questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions

Every time I ask a question related to database design or normalization, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659202/how-can-i-reference-an-intersection-table-of-a-many-to-many-relationship) one from today, I debate whether or not to tag the DBMS I am using.

The reason I debate it is because the question may not have anything to do with the DBMS that I am using. I don't want to add irrelevant tags to my questions.

On the flip side, the [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) tag has just over 292,000 questions where as database has just shy of 86,000. They both have 26.3k and 4.3k followers, respectively. I believe tagging [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) is likely to draw more attention to a question I need answered.

Is it selfish to tag in a way that draws attention, when it can be considered irrelevant? Of course, I mean in situations where it is not *blatantly* irrelevant, as if I had tagged 'Java' on that question.

Comment: Unlike tagging `eclipse` for a `Java` coding question, the DBMS you use may possibly impact your implementation, right? More a programmer than a DB person, but this is my impression, anyways.

Comment: If you believe the answers your question might attract won't make much difference if they contain specific MySQL syntax and peculiarities (which is what you ask by tagging as such), while it shouldn't matter, then you should be fine. I don't believe the behaviour you describe is wrong at any degree or against any community rules.

Comment: @Compass I can agree with that. Different DBMS may have different nuances but asking how to do something in Java would most likely have nothing to do with the IDE. That's a good point.